# Cache user click list item selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've a list of item and then there's change view option of the grid,  list, and compact view. Default when the user opens the link will be a grid(which I've already achieved).What I'm trying to achieve is when the user clicks on list view and then next time when the user opens that page again, it should be the view which was chosen by the user the last time.  [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4DGUV/72/)

**Here's my code:**

```js
$('li').on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('grid')) {
    $('#container ul').removeClass('list').addClass('grid');
  }
  if ($(this).hasClass('grid')) {
    $('#container ul').removeClass('compact').addClass('grid');
  }

  if ($(this).hasClass('list')) {
    $('#container ul').removeClass('grid').addClass('list');
  }
  if ($(this).hasClass('list')) {
    $('#container ul').removeClass('compact').addClass('list');
  }
  if ($(this).hasClass('compact')) {
    $('#container ul').removeClass('list').addClass('compact');
  } else if ($(this).hasClass('compact')) {
    $('#container ul').removeClass('grid').addClass('compact');
  }
});

$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.menu li').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var $div = $('#' + $(this).data('href'));
    $('.demo').not($div).hide();
    $div.slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.menu ul li button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(206, 0, 0, 1);
}

.active {
  background-color: rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
}

#container ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#container .buttons {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#container .list li {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #CCC;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#container .grid li {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  border-right: 1px dotted #CCC;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #CCC;
  padding: 20px;
}

#container .compact li {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50px;
  border-right: 1px dotted #CCC;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #CCC;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="grid"> <a href='#' id="show2">Grid</a></li>
    <li class="list"> <a href='#' id="show3">List</a></li>
    <li class="compact"> <a href='#' id="show1">Compact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <ul class="grid">
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
  </ul>
  <div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Have you looked into using cookies to store the choice?

Comment: ... or using the [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to store the choice as a cookie and then on document load check that cookie and set the layout accordingly, example

```js
$('li').on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('grid')) {
    document.cookie = "menuChoice=grid";
    $('#container ul').removeClass('list').addClass('grid');
    $('#container ul').removeClass('compact').addClass('grid');
  }

  if ($(this).hasClass('list')) {
    document.cookie = "menuChoice=list";
    $('#container ul').removeClass('grid').addClass('list');
    $('#container ul').removeClass('compact').addClass('list');
  }
  if ($(this).hasClass('compact')) {
    document.cookie = "menuChoice=compact";
    $('#container ul').removeClass('list').addClass('compact');
    $('#container ul').removeClass('grid').addClass('compact');
  }
});

$('document').ready(function() {
  switch (getCookie("menuChoice")) {
    case 'grid':
      $('#container ul').removeClass('list').addClass('grid');
      $('#container ul').removeClass('compact').addClass('grid');
      break;
    case 'list':
      $('#container ul').removeClass('list').addClass('list');
      $('#container ul').removeClass('compact').addClass('list');
      break;
    case 'compact':
      $('#container ul').removeClass('list').addClass('compact');
      $('#container ul').removeClass('compact').addClass('compact');
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  $('.menu li').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var $div = $('#' + $(this).data('href'));
    $('.demo').not($div).hide();
    $div.slideToggle();
  });
});

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

```css
.menu ul li button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(206, 0, 0, 1);
}

.active {
  background-color: rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
}

#container ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#container .buttons {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#container .list li {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #CCC;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#container .grid li {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  border-right: 1px dotted #CCC;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #CCC;
  padding: 20px;
}

#container .compact li {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50px;
  border-right: 1px dotted #CCC;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #CCC;
  padding: 20px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="grid"> <a href='#' id="show2">Grid</a>

    </li>
    <li class="list"> <a href='#' id="show3">List</a>

    </li>
    <li class="compact"> <a href='#' id="show1">Compact</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div id="container">
  <ul class="grid">

    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
  </ul>


  <div>

  </div>
```

As this is sandboxed cookies don't work see my JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Alessi42/7Ln5dc2t/ for a working example.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!